According to the Hebrew Gospels of Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24 and Luke 22:19-20, was Jesus’ blood shed FOR many or BECAUSE OF many?
According to the Hebrew Gospels of Matthew 26:28, Mark 14:24 and Luke 22:19-20, was Jesus’ blood shed for many or because of many?
The Greek uses peri and huper, and Aramaic S7191 D'aaKhLaaPH and S15688 - D'aaL ) which can also be translated as because of but were translated as for. The translators of the Hebrew Gospels used for, but what do the Hebrew Gospels say exactly and literally?
Further, do the Hebrew Gospels clarify if He poured or shed His own blood, or if the many shed His blood, or if His blood is being shed because of/by many? This will tie in with 1. Obviously, Jesus did not shed His own blood or Himself for us. People shed His blood. His blood was therefore clearly shed because of the sins of sinners. Does the Hebrew clarify this?
It is believed Jesus quoted Isaiah 53:5. Compare the Hebrew Gospels of Matthew 26:28, Mark 14:24, and Luke 22:19-20 with the Hebrew, Greek, and Aramaic of Isaiah 53:5 & 8 (Hebr. – Min; Greek -dia; Aramaic - S11636 – MetuL ), of Romans 4:25  (Greek -dia; Aramaic - S11636 - MetuL)and Psalm 69:20, Zechariah 12:10, Ezekiel 6:9, all Jesus’s words, Peter’s word in Acts 2-5 and what Jesus said to Paul on the Damascus Road.  All these indicate Jesus was denied, betrayed, wounded, bruised, crushed, and handed over by sinners, i.e. because of the sins of many. The Jews and Paul could never say: “Jesus died for us”, but could only say:  “We killed denied, betrayed, and crucified Him, He died because of our blindness and sinfulness.”
Logically also it must be because of, because the Jews, like all men, through sins of co-mission and omission, made and caused his grief, and wounds, spilled His blood, and caused His death. God foreknew and allowed it, but we did it - as with the death of all the prophets and saints. God did not do it for us.
There is a radical and massive difference in meaning, significance and implication between saying Jesus’ blood was shed for me or because of me. If it is for me, I have no guilt in His death, it is only for my benefit, I thankfully accept it and I try and live pleasing and thankful to Him. If it is because of, I am His murderer with every sin. I then need to confess, repent, make righty, stop with sin, and find deliverance and holiness. Without holiness, I shall continue piercing Him and shall not see Him.
Do the Hebrew Gospels of Matthew 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:19-20 shine more light on this?

Do you mean synoptic Gospels? Luke probably didn't even know Hebrew or Aramaic, at least not fluently.

Yes, the Gospels in Hebrews.

We do not have the Hebrew gospels - any such are translations of the original text in Greek.  A translation does not elucidate the original - it is the other way around!!

This is a sampling of Bible Translations that use the phrase “for many.”
Matthew 26:28 KJV

For this is my blood of the new testament, which is shed for many for the remission of sins.

Matthew 26:27-29 ASV

for this is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many unto remission of sins.  kingdom.

Matthew 26:27-29 CSB

For this is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins. .”

Matthew 26:27-29 CEB

This is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many so that their sins may be forgiven.

Matthew 26:27-29 ESV

for this is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins.

Matthew 26:27-29 Expanded Bible

This is my blood ·which is the new agreement that God makes with his people [or which confirms/establishes the new covenant; L of the new covenant; Ex. 24:8. Jer. 31:31–34]. This blood is poured out for many ·to forgive their [T for the remission of] sins [Is. 53:12].

Matthew 26:27-29 Mounce Reverse Interlinear New Testament

for this is · my blood of the covenant that is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins.

Matthew 26:27-29 RSV

for this is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins

The following are considered Literal Translation by
studybible.info
Matthew 26:28 Rotherham

For this is my blood of the covenant which for many is to be poured out, for remission of sins.

Matthew 26:28 Darby Translation

For this is my blood, that of the [new] covenant, that shed for many for remission of sins.

Matthew 26:28 YLT

for this is my blood of the new covenant, that for many is being poured out—to remission of sins;

A Few Translations do not incorporate the phrase “for many.”
It would seem that most Bible translations choose to Translate G4012  περί  peri  as for
Mattew 26:28
For(G1063) this(G5124) is(G2076) my(G3450) blood(G129) of(G3588) the(G3588) new(G2537) testament,(G1242) which is shed(G1632) for (G4012) many(G4183) for(G1519) the remission(G859) of sins.(G266)
G4012  περί  peri
Thayer Definition:

about, concerning, on account of, because of, around, near
Part of Speech: preposition


Yes, most English Bible translations choose to Translate G4012 περί peri as for. Therefore the question; Is the Hebrew also choosing "for" or "because of" which will be in line with Isaiah 53:5, 8, Romans 4:25 and the rest as I referred to?

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

It would seem you have confused yourself. Any Hebrew or Aramaic text would be a translation from Greek.  There are no original Hebrew or Aramaic texts in existence. If you're reaching for the original text, Greek is as close as you can get.
The word,"περὶ" seems to mean "for" in just about every case and never means "because" .
Please keep in mind that these texts have been poured over for literally millennia. There are controversial translation points, but this isn't one of them.

Thanks. See Mike's answer above. According to Thayer peri can be "because of."
Wuest Vol II  commentary on 1Pet 3:18 says: The word "for" is the translation of a Greek conjunction which means "because of."
Therefore the question: What does the Hebrew say?
